# Expo SQLite not inserting values into the table

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo, expo-sqlite

I am using expo-sqlite to create a table in a database. The database gets created/opened successfully and the table gets created too but when I insert some values into it, there's a strange error in log.

Following is my code

```
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';


const Onboarding = ({ navigation }) => {

      const db = SQLite.openDatabase('custom.db');
const createTable = () => {
     ;
  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
      'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS currencies (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT, sign TEXT);',
      [],
      () => console.log('Table created successfully'),
      (error) => console.log('Error creating table: ', error)
    );
  });
};

   

   const insertCurrency = (name, sign) => {

      
      db.transaction((tx) => {
         tx.executeSql(
            'INSERT INTO currencies (name, sign) VALUES (?, ?);',
            [name, sign],
            () => {
               console.log('CURRENCY INSERTED');
            },
            (error) => {
               console.log('Error occurred while inserting the currency:', error);
            }
         );
      });
   };

   const getAllEntries = () => {


  db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql(
      'SELECT * FROM currencies;',
      [],
      (_, result) => {
        const entries = result.rows._array;
        console.log("These are the entries:" + entries);
      },
      (_, error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
    );
  });
};


useEffect (()=>{
   createTable();
   insertCurrency('US Dollar', '$');
   getAllEntries();
})
   
return(
//rest of my code here
  )
```

Screenshot of the error is attached.
[console_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10sLe.png)

> Error occurred while inserting the currency: {"_complete": false, "_error": null, "_running": true, "_runningTimeout": false, "_sqlQueue": {"first": undefined, "last": undefined, "length": 0}, "_websqlDatabase": {"_currentTask": {"errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false, "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function anonymous]}, "_db": {"_closed": false, "_name": "custom.db"}, "_running": true, "_txnQueue": {"first": [Object], "last": [Object], "length": 1}, "closeAsync": [Function bound close], "deleteAsync": [Function bound deleteAsync], "exec": [Function bound exec], "version": "1.0"}}

I don't know what this error means or what should be done. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you provide the working code? I'm also facing this same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78242427/cannot-insert-in-sqlite-database-in-react-native-expo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Promise to show the resolve and reject where I found the actual error. It was "There is no column named sign". Then I used a query to show me the table structure and as it turned out, SQLite was converting the word "sign" to "code" and my column was being named code.

I deleted the table and made a new one with columns named (currency_id, currency_name, and currency_sign) and it works perfectly fine!

I hope it helps someone.