# cannot insert in SQLite database in react native expo

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, expo, native

I am new in react native expo. I am trying to create water reminder app, with react native expo and SQLite. I am constantly getting this error message when adding inserting data into table. ChatGPT and Google Gemini both not being able to solve.

LOG

> Table created successfully ERROR  Error checking date in database:
> {"_complete": false, "_error": null, "_running": true,
> "_runningTimeout": false, "_sqlQueue": {"first": undefined, "last":
> undefined, "length": 0}, "_websqlDatabase": {"_currentTask":
> {"errorCallback": [Function anonymous], "readOnly": false,
> "successCallback": [Function anonymous], "txnCallback": [Function
> anonymous]}, "_db": {"_closed": false, "_name": "waterTracker.db",
> "close": [Function closeAsync]}, "_running": true, "_txnQueue":
> {"first": undefined, "last": undefined, "length": 0}, "closeAsync":
> [Function bound closeAsync], "closeSync": [Function bound closeSync],
> "deleteAsync": [Function bound deleteAsync], "exec": [Function bound
> exec], "execAsync": [Function bound execAsync], "execRawQuery":
> [Function bound execRawQuery], "transactionAsync": [Function bound
> transactionAsync], "version": "1.0"}}

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import * as SQLite from 'expo-sqlite';
import { format } from 'date-fns';

const db = SQLite.openDatabase('waterTracker.db');

const App = () => {
  const [dailyIntake, setDailyIntake] = useState(0);
  const [currentDate, setCurrentDate] = useState('');
  const [isDbInitialized, setIsDbInitialized] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const initializeDatabase = () => {
      db.transaction(tx => {
        tx.executeSql(
          'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS waterIntake (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, date DATE, intakeChange INTEGER, totalIntake INTEGER)',
          [],
          () => {
            console.log('Table created successfully');
            setIsDbInitialized(true);
          },
          error => {
            console.error('Error creating table: ', error);
          }
        );
      });
    };

    initializeDatabase();

    const date = format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    setCurrentDate(date);

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT * FROM waterIntake WHERE date = ?',
        [date],
        (_, { rows }) => {
          if (rows.length === 0) {
            db.transaction(tx => {
              tx.executeSql(
                'INSERT INTO waterIntake (date, totalIntake) VALUES (?, ?)',
                [date, 0], // Set totalIntake to initial value
                () => {
                  console.log('Today\'s date inserted into the database');
                },
                error => {
                  console.error('Error inserting date into the database: ', error);
                }
              );
            });
          } else {
            // Fetch and set daily intake if date exists in the database
            setDailyIntake(rows.item(0).totalIntake);
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Error checking date in database: ', error);
        }
      );
    });
  }, []);

  const addWater = () => {
    const intakeChange = 1;
    if (isDbInitialized) {
      updateIntakeAndSaveHistory(intakeChange);
    } else {
      console.error('Database is not initialized yet.');
    }
  };

  const deleteWater = () => {
    if (dailyIntake > 0) {
      const intakeChange = -1;
      if (isDbInitialized) {
        updateIntakeAndSaveHistory(intakeChange);
      } else {
        console.error('Database is not initialized yet.');
      }
    }
  };

  const updateIntakeAndSaveHistory = (intakeChange) => {
    const newIntake = dailyIntake + intakeChange;
    setDailyIntake(newIntake);

    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'INSERT INTO waterIntake (date, intakeChange, totalIntake) VALUES (?, ?, ?)',
        [currentDate, intakeChange, newIntake],
        (_, results) => {
          if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
            console.log('Water intake history saved successfully');
          } else {
            console.log('Failed to save water intake history');
          }
        },
        error => {
          console.error('Error saving water intake history: ', error);
        }
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.header}>Water Tracker</Text>
      <Button title="Add Glass" onPress={addWater} />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Daily Intake: {dailyIntake} glasses</Text>
      <Button onPress={deleteWater} title="Delete Glass" />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Today's Date: {currentDate}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  header: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 20,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Comment: This code is correct, somehow this code is working on my friend's MacBook air and in expo dev snacks. I haven't found cause and solution. Do reply, if anyone has fixed this error.